# How do I show the following property of a factorial?

Tags: factorial

How do I show the following?

$$\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-(k+1))!}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \text{ for } k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$$

Comment: Use the definition of factorial.

Comment: It s obvious, since $\frac{n-k}{(n-k)!}=\frac{1}{(n-(k+1))!}$

Comment: @BabakSorouh, why?

Comment: @idealistikz: The Brian's is the complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s just algebra:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n-k}{k+1}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}&=\frac{(n-k)n!}{(k+1)k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac{(n-k)n!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}\quad\text{since}(k+1)!=(k+1)k!\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{(n-k)}n!}{(k+1)!\color{red}{(n-k)}(n-k-1)!}\quad\text{since}(n-k)!=(n-k)(n-k-1)!\\
&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!\big(n-(k+1)\big)!}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @idealistikz: No; where do you think that there should be one?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-(k+1))!}=\frac{n!}{(k+1)k!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(k+1)k!\frac{(n-k)!}{n-k}}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$